# Raid1 fail dev not suitable for any style of array

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

Hi I am trying to create raid lv1 from disks /dev/sdc /dev/sdd. 
In shortcut I got error

```
  mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
  device /dev/sdc1 not suitable for any style of array
```

But before you will send me link to other similar topics let me explain my issue.

```
fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd91338b1

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1953525167 1953523120 931.5G  5 Extended


Disk /dev/sdd: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1ed528e0

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 1953525167 1953523120 931.5G  5 Extended


mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda6
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda5
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdd1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdd
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdc1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdc
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb2
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb
mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sr0: No medium found
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram15
...
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/ram0
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically


root@..:/# mount | grep sdc

root@..:/# mount | grep sdd
```

So I don't mount my disks anywhere, I also checked that tere is no other raid installation:

```
root@...:/# mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdd1
mdadm: Unrecognised md component device - /dev/sdd1
root@...:/# mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc1
mdadm: Unrecognised md component device - /dev/sdc1
```

So now I don't know what I should check to diagnose what is wrong with my configuration. I also rebooted machine few times and tried liveCD as well, so now I am out of ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is during creation of partitions I choose default Extended, to force madm to work both partitions have to be in type "Linux raid autodetected" (fdisk type fd).

Hope it will help people with similar issues